# [SOLVED]Update Error: My data in Microsoft SQL server doesn't change after send http post succeeded (200)

Tags: flutter, dart

My data in Microsoft SQL server doesn't change after send http post succeeded (code 200).

**Help me with this please!!**.

Here is my stacktrace image, when i click "True" button many times but in SQL database didn't change it to "True". https://i.stack.imgur.com/dni2d.png

And here is what my app looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS1LN.png

[SOLVED]: add/change to HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" in headers.

```
Future<UserModel> createUser(String id, bool trangthaiapp, bool giatriapp) async{

**final response = await http.post(apiUrl, headers: headers,
body: json.encode({
"id_machdien": id,
"trang_thaiapp": trangthaiapp ? "True" : "False",
"giatri_app": giatriapp ? "True" : "False",
})
);**

if(response.statusCode == 200){
final String responseString = response.body;

return userModelFromJson(responseString);
}else{
return null;
}
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 UserModel _user;
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body:Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [ 
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                  final String id = "333";
                  final bool trangthaiapp = true;
                  final bool giatriapp= true;
                  final UserModel user = await createUser(id, trangthaiapp, giatriapp);

                  setState(() {
                    _user = user;
                  });
                },
              ),
                    RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                  final String id = "333";
                  final bool trangthaiapp = false;
                  final bool giatriapp= false;
                  final UserModel user = await createUser(id, trangthaiapp, giatriapp);
                  setState(() {
                    _user = user;
                  });
                  },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
}
 }
```

as for class user_model.dart below

```
 import 'dart:convert';

  UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

  class UserModel {
  String id;
  bool trangthaiapp;
  bool giatriapp;


   UserModel({
   this.id,
   this.trangthaiapp,
    this.giatriapp,

    });

    factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var userModel = UserModel(
    id: json["id_machdien"],
    trangthaiapp: json["trang_thaiapp"],
    giatriapp: json["giatri_app"],

    );
    return userModel;
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "id_machdien": id,
       "trang_thaiapp": trangthaiapp,
        "giatri_app": giatriapp,

       };
         }
```

***This*** "dmaisomdiasomcasicomaofnrsidkcfn siofnruosvnff sloujnovursgloujgnv rsjdjvbsd klvrb erglvb slvbjlerdsb jrsb fjvsb cvkjlsabvlovbflsvbarshkarsvbcarsvrbacyweqpfhvbrustvfghjsb chsbc shjbc slsdk cnvsd vlsdb gflsdfbnfsb" ***is some more detail that stack overflow ask for -.-***

Comment: Please provide value of "responseString"

Comment: @camillo777 oh i solved the problem, but a new error is here, check it below

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable "trangthaiapp" now is bool.

Body Request should be changed like this:

```
final response = await http.post(apiUrl, headers: headers,
body: json.encode({
"id_machdien": id,
"trang_thaiapp": trangthaiapp ? "1" : "0",
"giatri_app:": giatriapp,
})
);
```

Comment: thanks. with your help my debug console responded like this:
I/flutter ( 2361): 200
I/flutter ( 2361): 200
I/chatty  ( 2361): uid=10117(com.example.testhttp) Thread-2 identical 19 lines
I/flutter ( 2361): 200
I/flutter ( 2361): 200

.But it's doesn't change my data to "true" in my Microsoft SQL server database. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hello @Alars if it worked you can vote this answer up?

Comment: @Alars you should check the API what value of "trang_thaiapp" expects. Maybe you can try: trangthaiapp ? "True" : "False", or trangthaiapp ? "true" : "false",

Comment: i tried both "True" and "true" but it didn't change in my Microsoft SQL database server. Value of "trang_thaiapp" expects is "True" or "False"

Comment: @Alars try without the double quotes "" like this: trangthaiapp ? true : false,

Comment: it still the same, didn't change :<

Comment: @Alars this should be asked as another question; what is the service which translates http JSON data to SqlServer? Did you made it? Do the other fields update?

Comment: service i use is Web API and yes, i made it on visual studio 2019, other field still updated normal when i use Arduino http post it. But my API didn't have JSON translate. I can't edit on my API anymore, i only can edit on my app(flutter).